# Export all the models in a csv file

Tags: database, django, csv, export, prefetch

I want to export my database with the CSV format.
So far "my" code works for one table only...

Here are my models:

```
class ActsIdsModel(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, blank=False, null=False)
    ...lots of other fields...

class NationRespModel(models.Model):
    nationResp=models.CharField(max_length=2, unique=True)

class EUGroupRespModel(models.Model):
    euGroupResp=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class RespProposModel(models.Model):
    respPropos=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    nationResp = models.ForeignKey('NationRespModel', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    euGroupResp = models.ForeignKey('EUGroupRespModel', blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class GvtCompoModel(models.Model):
    gvtCompo= models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False, null=False)

class ActsInfoModel(models.Model):
    #id of the  act
    actId = models.OneToOneField(ActsIdsModel, primary_key=True)
    respProposId1=models.ForeignKey('RespProposModel', related_name='respProposId1', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    respProposId2=models.ForeignKey('RespProposModel', related_name='respProposId2', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    respProposId3=models.ForeignKey('RespProposModel', related_name='respProposId3', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    gvtCompo= models.ManyToManyField(GvtCompoModel)
    ...lots of other fields...
```

I use the code below to export all the data from one model:

```
import csv
from django.db.models.loading import get_model

    def dump(qs, outfile_path):
        model = qs.model
        writer = csv.writer(open(outfile_path, 'w'))

        headers = []
        for field in model._meta.fields:
            headers.append(field.name)
        writer.writerow(headers)

        for obj in qs:
            row = []
            for field in headers:
                val = getattr(obj, field)
                if callable(val):
                    val = val()
                if type(val) == unicode:
                    val = val.encode("utf-8")
                row.append(val)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

(source: http://palewi.re/posts/2009/03/03/django-recipe-dump-your-queryset-out-as-a-csv-file/)

Here is how I get all my models (main model + models linked to the main one):

```
db_queryset=ActsInfoModel.objects.select_related().all().prefetch_related('gvtCompo')
```

**My question is: how can I link this queryset to the dump function? So far I get the data from ActsInfoModel only...**

Should I use the code below, used to display and check all the data:

```
for act in db_queryset.iterator():
    #ActsIdsModel
    for field in act.actId.__class__._meta.fields:
        print field.name, getattr(act.actId, field.name)
    #ActsInformationModel
    for field in act.__class__._meta.fields:
        print field.name, getattr(act, field.name)
    #RespProposModel (3 respPropos)
    for index in xrange(1,4):
        index=str(index)
        try:
            print getattr(act, "respProposId"+index).respPropos
            print getattr(act, "respProposId"+index).nationResp.nationResp
            print getattr(act, "respProposId"+index).euGroupResp.euGroupResp
        except Exception, e:
            print "exception", e
    #NPModel (gvtCompo)
    for gvtCompo in act.gvtCompo.all():
        print "gvtCompo", gvtCompo.gvtCompo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
**Export to CSV using the Django ORM**
```

Django apps tend to be pretty data heavy. One common task is exporting sets of data to csv (comma separated values), a plain text file which can be loaded up in a spreadsheet and manipulated further. The first thing to do is make sure you know about the Python csv library.

If you are exporting all of you data with respect to one model, here is
 a quick way to do it and keep your code cleaner using values_list and the
 Django ORM query shorthand. Start by defining your export as a data structure.

```
 export_info = [
        ("Role", "role__name"),
        ("Department", "department"),
        ("Last Name", "person__last_name"),
        ("First Name", "person__first_name"),
    ]
```

The first item in the tuple is the row header and the second item is an ORM path to the value you want. It will be passed in to values_list. One quirk to note is if you have a relationship and you don't specify the field on the relationship are you interested in you will just get the id for the object. The model's unicode method isn't called. For a better idea here is what the models would look like in this example.

```
class Position(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey("Role")
    department = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    person = models.ForeignKey("Person")

class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
The core logic looks like this.

global export_info
positions = Position.objects.all().order_by("role__name", 
                                            "person__last_name")
# The inverse of zip is zip
headers, fields = zip(*export_info)     
rows = [headers]
for position in positions:
    qs = Position.objects.filter(pk=position.id)    
    # convert values like datetimes into unicode objects
    rows.append([unicode(v) for v in qs.values_list(*fields)[0]])
```

The last line is where the magic happens. I suggest going through it in your interpreter if you are confused about what it does. When this code is done you will have the list of rows which are your csv file. All that is left is to write the result to a proxy file and return it in a response.

```
f = StringIO.StringIO()
writer = UnicodeWriter(f)
for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(row)
response = HttpResponse(f.getvalue(), mimetype="text/csv")  
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=export.csv'
return response
```

To get StringIO do "import cStringIO as StringIO". The UnicodeWriter for csv is a bit of custom code inspired by this section of the Python docs.
 You can use the normal csv library writer if all your data is ASCII and different file proxy object if you like.

[source](http://albertoconnor.ca/blog/2012/May/17/export-csv-using-django-orm)

Comment: Can I use this for exporting all the models linked to the main one ActsInfoModel? I  read "If you are exporting all of you data with respect to one model"...